# Automating PostgreSQL query so I don't have to change schema name each time in sql query

Tags: postgresql, schema, postgis

I have a multistep PostgreSQL + PostGIS query/geoprocessing operation that I need to change the schema name for the output tables each time I run it.  The base tables I use are all in another schema that doesn't change, but the outputs from the query are created in another project schema each time.

For example, I have a new project 'project_abc_2023' which is a new schema I create.  Currently, I have to change all the output table schema names to this new 'project_abc_2023' schema.  I would like to be able to change these schema names to the project schema I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SEARCH-PATH).

If the schema for the base tables is `base_schema`, you could use code like this:

```
SET search_path TO project_abc_2023;

INSERT INTO target_table
SELECT ...
FROM base_schema.table1
   JOIN base_schema.table2
...
```

That is, you add an explicit schema qualification to the base tables and use the target tables without schema qualification, so that PostgreSQL looks for them using the `search_path`.

Comment: I recommend to use `begin; set local search_path ..; insert... end;` to be safe